# Constantly getting ERR_CONNECTION_RESET or ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED on Chrome that goes away after a couple seconds

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, google-chrome, internet, safari

I am having an issue with Chrome on 2017 Macbook Pro.

I am constantly getting ERR_CONNECTION_RESET or ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED on certain websites. This happens once every few days and started recently. Sometimes, the problem goes away when the website automatically reloads in a second. Other times it will go away when i refresh the page a few times or click back and then reclick the link. Sometime, web pages will not show that error, but they will not load the full page  (mostly white screen with a bunch of blue links, and no pictures loading) as if I am on a very slow internet connection. When trying Safari, i often get a similar problem, that Safari cannot establish a connection because the connection is not secure. This isn't really a huge inconvenience as the problem usually goes away on it's own, but I was wondering if anyone knew what was causing this? Is this the result of a man in the middle attack trying to interrupt the connection?

I do not have any proxy servers installed, but I do have Avast anti-virus, of which the certificate authority is replacing the certificates of many websites. However, I believe that I have also had this be the case before the problem occurred. In addition, this is only happening on my current laptop (Macbook pro 2017), but it happened on two different internet connections in two different states, when other machines on both internet connections were fine, (including a different macbook pro, 2018). One internet connection speed was relatively slow, but the other was decent. Consequently, I suspected malware on this machine, but Avast scanned my cpu and found no problems.

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks.

Comment: Disable Avast. That seems like the most likely cause. Something is interrupting your connection. That sounds like Avast.

Comment: So far, disabling the particular functions within avast that cause it to "scan secure connections" has stopped Avast from replacing website certificates with their own certificate and has fixed the issue. Thanks!